# Physical symbols (italic)

Tags: symbols, siunitx, italic, physics

Symbols for quantities are written in italics.

I know that I can use `\qty{}{}` for numbers and units.

Is there a similar command for symbols?

Or would this be okay?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{siunitx}
\author{}
\date{January 2024}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
$$m=\qty{2}{\kg}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by symbols in this case?

Comment: I hope my understanding is correct. In this case, I think of m as a symbol for the quantity mass

Comment: Can you please provide some examples. `m` is just a variable, imo should not need any special treatment.

Comment: @daleif m as a symbol for mass, p as a symbols for momentum, v as a symbol for velocity...
I was just wondering whether there exists a specific command?

Comment: Those are just variables, same as they would be in non-physics mathematics. As such, there's no specific command for them, and you typeset them in the same way as regular variables.

Comment: @bonk thank you.

Comment: unrelated, but you should not use `$$...$$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/36296